# New bathroom counters and sinks, what is the proper way to handle the difference in supply line length

Tags: plumbing, water, faucet, extension

So I got new counters and faucets. Unfortunately, the old faucet had an extender on the supply lines that the new one does not, additionally, it doesn't appear to something i can swap from old to new. Due to this, the water supply lines are too short to reach the new sink. What is the best way to handle this?

Old sink connector

[image]

New sink connector

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typically use braided steel supply lines to connect the sink to your supply.

[image: supply lines under sink]

You can get anything from a few inches long to a couple feet long.

[image: braided steel supply hose]

Comment: They have built-in rubber washers, so don't go nuts tightening them. Think garden hose plus half a turn.